# Why is naive string search algorithm faster?

Tags: string, algorithm, search

I'm testing string search algorithms from this site: [EXACT STRING MATCHING ALGORITHMS. Christian Charras, Thierry Lecroq](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/index.html). Test text is a random sequence of DNA bases (ACGT) of 1 GByte size. Test patterns are a list of random sequences of random size (1kB max). Test system is a AMD Phenom II x4 955 at 3.2 GHz, 4 GB of RAM and Windows 7 64 bits. Code witten in C and compiled with MinGW with -O3 flag.

Naive search algorithm takes 4 seconds for short patterns to 8 seconds for 1kB patterns. Deterministic finite state machine takes 2 seconds for short patterns to 4 seconds for 1kB patterns. Boyer-Moore algorithm takes 4 seconds for very short patters, about 1/2 second for short pattherns and 2 seconds for 1kB patterns. The remaining algorithm performance is worst than naive search algorithm.

How can be naive search algorithm search algorithm faster than most other algorithms?

How can a deterministic finite state machine implemented with a transition table (O(n) execution time always) be 2 to 8 times slower than Boyer-Moore algorithm? Yes, BM best case is O(n/m), but his average case is O(n) and worst case is O(nm).

Answer (score 4):

There is no perfect string matching algorithm which is best for all circumstances.

Boyer-Moore (and Horspool, Sunday etc.) work by creating jump tables ('How far can I move the search pointer when the characters do **not** match? The more distinct letters in the strings, the better the positive impact. You can imagine, that a string with only 4 distinct letters creates a jump table with a maximum of 3 shifts per mismatch. Whereas searching an english word with case sensitive may result in a jumptable with (A-Z + a-z + punctiation) max. approx 55 shifts per mismatch.

On the other hand, there is a negative impact on both preparation (i.e. calculating the jump tables) and looping itself. So these algorithms perform poor on short strings (preparation creates an overhead) and strings with only a few distict letters (as mentioned before)

The naive search algorithm is very compact and there are very little operations inside the loop, so loop runs fast. As there is no overhead it performs better when searching short strings.

The (compared to the naive search) quite complex loop operations of a BM algorithm take much longer per loop run. This (partly) compensates for the positive performance impact of the jump tables.

So although you are using long strings, the small alphabet (=small jump tables) makes BM perform poorly. A KMP has less overhead in the loop (the jump table is smaller in general, but is similar to the BM with small alphabets) and so the KMP performs so well.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically good algorithms (lower time complexity) often have high bookkeeping costs that can overwhelm that of a naive algorithm for small problem sizes. Also implementation details matter. By optimizing an implementation you can sometimes improve runtime by factors of 2 or more.

Answer (score 2):

The naive implementation actually has a linear *expected* running time (same as BM/KMP, etc) for random input data. I could not write a full proof here but it's accessible from *Algorithms Design Techniques and Analysis*.

Most exact matching algorithms are optimized version of the naive implementation to prevent being slowed down by certain patterns. For instance, suppose we are searching for:

```
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
```

on a stream of:

```
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
```

It fails at the `b` for lots of times. KMP/BM implementations are contrived to prevent repeatedly comparing the `a`s. However, if the sequence is random by itself, such conditions are almost impossible to appear and the naive implementation is likely to work better due to its lower overhead in bookkeeping or possibly better spatial/temporal locality.

And, yeah, I'm not sure DNA sequences are random. Or alternatively are repetitions common in them. Anyway there's no way to examine this carefully without representative data.

Comment: And, yeah, I'm not sure DNA sequences are random. Or alternatively are repetitions common in them. Anyway there's no way to examine this carefully without representative data.

Comment: All those smart string matching algorithms perform better than the naive matching if the text (hay) is fairly long, the needle not too short and the alphabet, i.e. the number of different characters in large. So even random strings will perform well as the propability of getting a nice shift value increases with the alphabet size and the needle length.